# Is there any way to just see not edit a user cognos dashboard?

Tags: dashboard, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I use [cognos-11](/questions/tagged/cognos-11) and I made a [dashboard](/questions/tagged/dashboard) for a **cognos** consumer. I delivered it but the consumer when open  it  sees the edit/preview icon.
I  want the consumer to just open the dashboard, filtering the data and use the various drill downs without has the ability to edit or save  my dashboard.

I found the following at the IBM Support 
[allow-users-view-dashboards](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/allow-users-view-dashboards-and-remove-ability-create-edit-and-save-dashboards)

but  if I apply it then the consumer  cannot be able to create  his own new dashboard.

Consumer can have the ability to create his dashborads but when I give him mine he can only view/open it.
Can you give me any suggestion on how can I do it ?

Comment: Just want to clarify.  You want the user to be able to create their own dashboards AND not be able to edit a specific dashboard created by an author?

Comment: VAI Jason  Exactly.